# Regex - match the first word of a filename inside a path

Tags: regex

Here is an examples and the result should match like this:

```
Controllers/Employees/File | Match = File

Controllers/Employees2/File2.php | Match = File2

Controllers/Employees3/File3.class.php | Match = File3
```

I only know the regex which will get the string after the last `/` which is this:

```
[^/]*$
```

But, this will match the full filename and even the filetype.
I've tried adding positive lookahead but it didn't work the way it supposed to be. Need help.

Comment: What do you mean by a word?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think OP's example suggests that they want `File`, `File2`, and `File3` respectively from the given paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```
(?<=^|\/)[^\/.]+(?=[^\/]*$)
```

- `(?<=^|\/)` - behind me there needs to be a slash or start of the string
- `[^\/.]+` - get the filename
- `(?=[^\/]*$)` - ahead of me there can be no slashes till the end of the string

https://regex101.com/r/HyY0wr/1